# Adding methods in an object's prototype through a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add several methods to an object at once by using a for loop.

What I have is an array which has names of several events like click, load, etc. in an array and as such it will be really easy for me to insert these events to my library's object. However, I am not able to add the methods through the loop to my object.

Here's my code:

```
function(something) myLibrary {

if(this === window) {return new myLibrary }

this.e = document.getElementById(something);

}

var eventsArr = ['click','load','drag','drop'];

var addEventToProto = function (method) {

    if(!myLibrary.hasOwnProperty(method)) {
        myLibrary.prototype[method] = function (fn) { addEventListener(this.e, method, fn); };
    }

};

for (i = 0; i < eventsArr.length; i += 1) {
    addEventToProto(eventsArr[i]);
};
```

If you need more information then please leave a comment.

Comment: So sorry, forgot to edit the code.!

Comment: `myLibrary` is an objet, not a function. It doesn't have a property called `prototype`.

Comment: @basilikum I actually foolishly wrote a sample of my library. Please have a look again. And one more thing, I coded my actual library inside an IIFE (just saying).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a constructor function and manipulate the `prototype` property of that function instead. Object don't have an exposed `prototype` property, only functions have. When you create and instance, using a constructor function, then the internal `[[prototype]]` property of the resulting object will be set to point to the exposed `prototype` property of the constructor function. You can manipulate the `prototype` property even after instanciating an object:

```
function myLibraryConstructor() {
    this.e = document.getElementById('someElement!');
}

var myLibrary = new myLibraryConstructor();

var eventsArr = ['click','load','drag','drop'];

var addEventToProto = function (method) {

    if(!myLibrary.hasOwnProperty(method)) {
        myLibraryConstructor.prototype[method] = function (fn) { addEventListener(this.e, method, fn); };
    }

};

for (i = 0; i < eventsArr.length; i += 1) {
    addEventToProto(eventsArr[i]);
};
```

Comment: I just recently did the looping inside my costructor and I was successfully able to add 66 events to my prototype! Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you're doing the looping in your constructor you might be adding the methods to every instance created rather than adding them once to the prototype. If you are actually adding them to the prototype, then you might be adding them each time you create an instance, which would be unnecessary and probably considered a bug. This later scenario would not cause buggy behavior, though, as the properties on the prototype would be over-written rather than appended.